# Cross Database Migrations in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I want my application to work with various databases like MSSQL, MySQL and SQLite. Connecting works just fine by changing the connection strings in the configuration, and I managed to apply database specific configuration like this:

```
public class ServerDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public ServerDbConfiguration()
    {
        switch (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseProvider"].ToUpper())
        {
            case "MYSQL":
                SetHistoryContext("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", (conn, schema) => new ServerHistoryContext(conn, schema));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Now I am looking for a way to achieve the same with migrations. After running `Add-Migration` against a MSSQL database, I get something like this:

```
public partial class Initial : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Jobs",
            c => new
                {
                    id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.id);
        // ....
    }
}
```

But obviously there is no way `dbo.Jobs` is going to resolve to a table name in anything else than MSSQL.

How can I have multiple migrations for various databases in a single project? Or if I can't, what is the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: Quite a few RDBMSs will recognise "dbo.jobs" provided there is a schema called "dbo".  Perhaps your schema name needs to be dynamic.  Perhaps you need an owner/schema that reliably exists on each of the possible target databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command line tools accept a `-configuration` parameter to specify the configuration class and use the namespace of the configuration class to discover/add the migrations. I have two namespaces:

- Server.Migrations.MSSQL

  - Configuration
  - InitialMigration ...
- Server.Migrations.MySQL

  - Configuration
  - InitialMigration ...

To add a new migration:

```
Add-Migration -configuration Server.Migrations.MSSQL.Configuration MyNewMigration
```

Then a new migration under the `Server.Migrations.MSSQL` namespace is added. Unfortunately it is always stored in the `Migrations/` folder so you need to move it manually.

To apply the migrations, run:

```
Update-Database -configuration Server.Migrations.MSSQL.Configuration
```

You can also run the migrations via your code, like:

```
System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration;

switch (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseProvider"].ToUpper())
{
    case "MYSQL":
        configuration = new Migrations.MySQL.Configuration();
        configuration.MigrationsNamespace = "Server.Migrations.MySQL";
        break;
    case "MSSQL":
        configuration = new Migrations.MSSQL.Configuration();
        configuration.MigrationsNamespace = "Server.Migrations.MSSQL";
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception("Invalid DatabaseProvider, please check your config");
}

configuration.ContextType = typeof(Context);
configuration.MigrationsAssembly = configuration.ContextType.Assembly;

var migrator = new System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator(configuration);
migrator.Update();
```